# Spacing around overlaid TikZ picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing

## Input

```
\documentclass[version=last,paper=A4,parskip=half]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mlmodern}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[final,babel]{microtype}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc,fit}
\tcbuselibrary{most}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-1]

{%
  \tcbset{%
    enhanced,%
    size=fbox,%
    on line,%
    box align=center,%
    fonttitle=\small,%
    fontupper=\small,%
    fontlower=\small,%
    halign title=center,%
    halign upper=center,%
    halign lower=center,%
  }%
  \begin{tcolorbox}[title=Microservices,remember as=JSON,width=.2\linewidth]
    JSON events\tcblower{}Kafka
  \end{tcolorbox}%
  \hfill%
  \begin{tcolorbox}[title=Databricks,remember as=Spark,width=.2\linewidth]
    Spark\tcblower{}EC2 \& EBS
  \end{tcolorbox}%
  \hfill%
  \begin{minipage}{.2\linewidth}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[remember as=Oracle]
      Oracle
    \end{tcolorbox}%
    \\%
    \begin{tcolorbox}[remember as=Delta]
      Delta Lake\tcblower{}S3
    \end{tcolorbox}
  \end{minipage}%
  \hfill%
  \begin{minipage}{.15\linewidth}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[remember as=Exasol]
      Exasol
    \end{tcolorbox}%
    \\%
    \begin{tcolorbox}[remember as=Presto]
      Presto
    \end{tcolorbox}%
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[%
    overlay,%
    remember picture,%
    >=Stealth,%
    shorten >=1pt,%
    shorten <=1pt,%
    surround/.style 2 args={%
      draw,%
      rectangle,%
      thick,%
      dotted,%
      fit=#1,%
      inner sep=8pt,%
      label={[align=center,scale=0.75]#2},%
    },%
    ]

    \coordinate (Spark-SSE)  at ($(Spark.south)!0.5!(Spark.south east)$);
    \coordinate (Spark-NNE)  at ($(Spark.north)!0.5!(Spark.north east)$);
    \coordinate (Delta-SSW)  at ($(Delta.south)!0.5!(Delta.south west)$);
    \coordinate (Exasol-NNW) at ($(Exasol.north)!0.5!(Exasol.north west)$);

    \path[->]
    (JSON)      edge                                       (Spark)
    (Spark)     edge                                       (Oracle)
    (Oracle)    edge                                       (Exasol)
    (Spark)     edge                                       (Delta)
    (Delta)     edge[<->]                                  (Presto)
    (Delta-SSW) edge[out=-150,in=-30]
                node[midway,below,scale=0.75] {SNS \& SQS} (Spark-SSE)
    (Spark-NNE) edge[out=30,in=150]                        (Exasol-NNW);

    \node[surround={(Spark)}{Airflow}]                          (Scheduling) {};
    \node[surround={(Exasol)(Presto)}{Superset\\MicroStrategy}] (Reporting)  {};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\lipsum[2-2]
\end{document}
```

## Output

[Click to view output with no spacing around overlaid TikZ picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCJA7.png)

## Question

How can I automatically add spacing around the overlaid TikZ picture so that its contents do not go over the surrounding text?

Comment: May be `vspace{}` before and after the drawing

Comment: I'd do your example only with Ti*k*Z nodes. No tcolorboxes and not overlayed. I think that it'll be easier this way. Only an idea...

Comment: You have several alignment issues between your tcolorboxes. I think it would be better if done only in a single tikzpicture, rather that with an overlay on your tcboxes. Maybe could you nest your tcboxes into tikz nodes if you really want to use tcolorbox.

Comment: @SebGlav — what alignment issues exactly?  I don’t think there are any.  But you and Juan are probably right that I should look into doing everything with TikZ nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would draw you image as pure Ti*k*Z picture and enclose it in a `center` environment. In the picture are not used `remember picture` and `overlay` options, which cause your problem. In comparison to your solution with `tcolorbox` code is simpler, more clear and shorter:

[image]

(red lines are text borders)

```
\documentclass[version=last,paper=A4,parskip=half]{scrartcl}
%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%
\usepackage{lipsum}                             % for dummy text
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                fit,
                positioning,
                quotes,
                shapes.multipart}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]

\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
  node distance = 1mm and 0.05\linewidth,
every edge/.append style = {draw, -Stealth},
every label/.append style = {align=center},
FIT/.style = {draw, densely dashed, rounded corners=2pt,
              fit=#1, node contents={} },
MPV/.style = {
        rectangle split parts=3, 
        shape=rectangle split, 
        rectangle split draw splits=false,
        rectangle split part fill={black, gray!30},
        draw, rounded corners=1pt,
        inner sep=1mm, text width=0.2\linewidth, align=center,
        },
  N/.style = {draw, rounded corners=1pt, fill=gray!30,
        text width=0.18\linewidth, align=center}
                        ]
\node (n1)  [MPV] {%
        \nodepart{one}   \textcolor{white}{\textbf{Microservices}}
        \nodepart{two}   JSOM events
        \nodepart{three} Kafka};
        \draw[dashed]   (n1.two split west) -- (n1.two split east);
\node (n2)  [MPV, right=of n1] {%
        \nodepart{one}   \textcolor{white}{\textbf{Databricks}}
        \nodepart{two}   Spark
        \nodepart{three} EC2 \& EBS};
        \draw[dashed]   (n2.two split west) -- (n2.two split east);
    \node[FIT=(n2)];
\node (n3a) [N, right=of n2.one east] 
        {Oracle};
\node (n3b) [N,below=of n3a] 
        {Exasol\\S3};
        \draw[dashed]   (n3b.west) -- (n3b.east);
\node (n4a) [N, right=of n3a.south east]
        {Oracle};
\node (n4b) [N, below=of n4a]
        {Presto};
        \draw[dashed]   (n3b.west) -- (n3b.east);
    \node[FIT=(n4a) (n4b), label={Superset\\MicroStrategy}];
% connections
\draw   (n1) edge (n2)
        (n2) edge (n3a)
        (n2) edge (n3b)
        (n3a)   edge    (n4a);
\draw[Stealth-Stealth]  (n4b)   edge    (n3b);
%
\draw   (n2.75)    edge[bend left] (n4a)
        (n3b)   edge[bend left=30,"SNS \& SQS"] (n2.285);
%
\draw[-Stealth] (n1) -- (n2);
   \end{tikzpicture}                 
\end{center}
\lipsum[12]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much — I was not aware of `rectangle split`!